# Please recommend a Firefox extension which can select a specified element on page

Tags: wordpress, firefox-addon

I want to get a extension, which can do,

1. Put a button on toolbar,
2. After click the button, I can select any Elements (a div, or a table, and so on) by clicking it.
3. After I select a button, display a layer, which display the element I just select in it, and the screen is masked with grey.

Basically, what I want is an extension which can capture a part of the screen, and then I can save it to my Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mozilla FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Comment: Refael, thanks for your reply.But Firebug may don't meet my requirement. I need select a element in page, not in firebug window, and I can save the element selected to my wordpress.